# Request Handler for ajax file upload in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, blazemeter

I have Web Page which uses Ajax call for file upload using JSF primfaces component. I want to test this upload using Jmeter. Check this Link for Component https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/upload/auto.xhtml 
how can I replicate this using jmeter help needed in creating .jmx

Answer (score 0):

**Just record it** using [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder), it is smart enough to capture the request and convert it into the relevant [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler.

Make sure you copy the file, you are uploading to the "bin" folder of JMeter installation, otherwise you may face an issue during the recording as JMeter won't be able to locate the file. see [Recording File Uploads with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-file-uploads-jmeter) article for more details.